# Where is the menubar in evince on arch?

Tags: arch-linux, evince

I just installed the pdf viewer evince on arch linux and don't find the menubar.
I tried the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key but nothing happens. I also tried all other keys on my keyboard and read the FAQ on the product page.

What I was trying to do was set the view mode to continuous scrolling and two-page-layout, but that are just examples. At the moment I just can scroll, zoom and print because there are buttons and shortcuts for these actions.

Answer (score 1):

There *is* no menubar. All functions have been put in either the <kbd>F10</kbd> menu, or the <kbd>Win</kbd><kbd>F10</kbd> global app menu. (There really weren't many functions to start with.)

Generally, <kbd>F10</kbd> to open the application menu is more common than <kbd>Alt</kbd>. But I don't know if there's a shortcut for the "view options" popup, other than some careful tabbing.

The older "classic" Evince version is part of MATE and available as `atril` (or `atril-gtk3`).

Comment: Unfortunately F10 or Win+F10 don't do anything in my case either.

Comment: Thank you! `atril` is the answer to my prayers!
I hate the three bar menu and feel it has no place on a desktop system. Great idea for tablets and phones where there is limited screen real-estate but on a desktop it just creates an extra step (one big menu rather than a categorised one) and placing it on the right rather than left interrupts my established workflow and reflexes.
Installed Atril and happily sailing on.